# antlr4 parsing hexfile skips first digit

Tags: antlr4

I have an antlr grammer as follows

```
grammar memhex;
hexfile: statement* EOF;
statement: Comment|words;
words: (address|data)+;
address: '@'HEX;
data:HEX;
WS: ('  '|'\t'|Newline) -> skip;
HEX: [a-fA-F0-9]+;
Newline:('\n'|'\r')+;
fragment BlockComment: '/*' .*? '*/' ;
fragment LineComment: '//' .*? Newline;
Comment: (BlockComment|LineComment) -> skip;
```

The test hex file used to test this grammar is

```
/* http://srecord.sourceforge.net/ */
@00000000 0030000031010000 DD000000C5000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
@00000004 0000000000000000 00000000E9000000 0000000000000000 F500000001010000
```

on running the test I see that the first digit of each data word is not recognised resulting in the following error

```
line 2:9 token recognition error at: ' 0'
line 2:26 token recognition error at: ' D'
line 2:43 token recognition error at: ' 0'
line 2:60 token recognition error at: ' 0'
line 3:9 token recognition error at: ' 0'
line 3:26 token recognition error at: ' 0'
line 3:43 token recognition error at: ' 0'
line 3:60 token recognition error at: ' F'
```

I am unable to figure out what is the bug in my grammar...

Comment: You define WS with a string literal with two spaces, not one. Change `'  '` to `' '` in your grammar, and it works. Also, you should not be defining Newline without the "fragment" keyword. This is because it's misleading: Newline cannot be returned as a lexer token because "Antlr lexers will match the first rule listed in the grammar if the string can match more than one lexer rule." Also, you should use "channel(HIDDEN)" instead of "skip", so you can see how the lexer tokenizes everything. Always print out the tokens produced when you see errors to debug your grammar.